# Power Point got crashed when manipulating shapes in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

When transforming Power Point shapes using Excel VBA, Power Point got crashed and closed by itself
(PC environtment : Windows 10 using MS Office Profesional Plus 2013) but when using other PC (Windows 7 using MS Office Profesional Plus 2013) it run just fine

Here my Code :

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart")
    i = wb.Cells(wb.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For z = 1 To i
        sld = sld + 1
        PPTemp.Slides(2).Copy
        PPPres.Slides.Paste sld
        Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(sld)
        PPSlide.Shapes("Title").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Quantitative Ad Measurement Result" & vbNewLine & wb.Cells(z, 1).Value
        PPSlide.Shapes("Text 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "The VIRTUAL ADS has " & IIf(wb.Cells(z, 1).Value < 0, WorksheetFunction.Text(Abs(wb.Cells(z, 2).Value), "0%") & " lower ", WorksheetFunction.Text(Abs(wb.Cells(z, 2).Value), "0%") & " higher ") & " higher TVR compared to the commercial break TVR on average."
        PPSlide.Shapes("Footer").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Data TVR based on TVR MBM Program & Break Program " & WorksheetFunction.Proper(wa.Range("D6").Value)
        wb.ChartObjects(wb.Cells(z, 1).Value & " " & wb.Cells(z, 3).Value).Copy
        PPSlide.Shapes.Paste
        Set PPShape = PPSlide.Shapes(PPSlide.Shapes.Count)
        PPShape.Width = 800
        PPShape.Height = 380
        PPShape.Top = 90
        PPShape.Left = 80
        PPPres.Slides(1).Select
    Next z
```

I hope to know the reason why Power Point got crashed, because when i put break in `PPPres.Slides(1).Select` and press run button trough the loops, the power point doesn't crashed and my code run till end

Comment: I/O operations (open, save, copy, paste, etc.) run more slowly that your code. This is a common problem, do an internet search on _Sleep_, _Wait_ and _DoEvents_ to find solutions.

Comment: Why is there a `Select` (`PPPres.Slides(1).Select`)? by removing that you may solve your issues.